# Преобразовать углы Эйлера в полряные координаты и обратно

Tags: c++, математика, qt5, opengl

Есть задача рисовать объекты на земной поверности с помощью Qt5 и OpenGL. При этом систему координат, в которой находятся эти объекты можно описать так:

- плоскость OXY совпадает с плоскостью земной поверхности;
- ось OZ направлена вверх от земной поверхности;
- направление оси OY совпадает с направлением на "север".

Направление линии визирования объекта задаётся углом азимута θ∈(0,360°) и углом места ψ∈(0,90°). Угол азимута отсчитывается от оси OY против часовой стрелки, если смотреть вдоль положительного направления оси OZ. Угол места отсчитывается от плоскости OXY.
Логика самой программы работает в углах Эйлера и кватернионах, однако пользователю надо всё показывать в углах как описано выше.
Таким образом, углы Эйлера перевожу в полярные координаты:

```
QVector2D CoordinateSystemGround::toPolar(const QVector3D& euler) const {
    float z = euler.z();
    if(z < 0.0f)
        z += 360.0f;
    return QVector2D(z, 90.0f - euler.x());
}
```

С этим кодом вроде проблем нет.
А вот с переводом из полярных координат в углы Эйлера ничего не получается:

```
QVector3D CoordinateSystemGround::fromPolar(const QVector2D& polar) const {
    float x = qDegreesToRadians(90.0f - polar.y());
    float z = qDegreesToRadians(polar.x());
    float y = qAtan(qTan(x) * qSin(z));
    y = qRadiansToDegrees(y);
    return QVector3D(90.0f - polar.y(), y, polar.x());
}
```

Вроде вращение начинается вокруг оси Z, но потом куда-то уходит в бок. Подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Углы господина Эйлера характеризуют поворот вокруг центра масс в трех плоскостях, а полярные координаты точку на плоской поверхности.

Comment: Всё правильно. Например, если взять систему координат, в которой ось Y направлена вверх, а земля - плоскость XZ, то азимут - поворот вокруг оси Y, а угол места - вокруг X. При этом эти самые углы поворота и есть два из трёх углов Эйлера.

Comment: я полагяю речь идет о 2х угловых компонентах сферической ск?

Comment: и если для прямого преобразования Вы применяете только сложение и вычитание, почему для обратного вдруг синус, арктангенс..

Comment: Да, всё верно понимаете.Да вот в том-то и дело, что если бы обратное работало, то я бы тут не спрашивал... :)

Comment: а по какому принципу Вы пытаетесь восстановить компонент y, если при прямом переводе он просто теряется?

Comment: Информации не хватает. Ось X - на восток? Какая система координат у камеры? (x - вправо, y - вверх, z - назад?) Как именно у вас сделаны углы эйлера? (Вокруг каких осей, в каком порядке поворачивается система координат? На английской википедии есть [куча вариантов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).)

Comment: Что-то меня очень смущает использование `euler.z()` в качестве азимута... И у меня тот же вопрос, что и у Stranger in the Q. Как можно из двух углов получить три? Это не потому, что у вас "крен" всегда нулевой?

Comment: Ось Х - на восток, камера смотрит в центр системы кооринат и "верх" камеры получается должен совпадать с осью Z. Углы эйлера берутся от кватерниона: "eulerAngles.z() degrees around the z axis, eulerAngles.x() degrees around the x axis, and eulerAngles.y() degrees around the y axis (in that order)." Не исключаю, что в прямом коде тоже ошибка...

Comment: *""верх" камеры получается должен совпадать с осью Z"* Не уверен, что мы друг друга поняли. Вы говорите про ось Z в мировой системе координат (то есть в неповернутой), или в системе координат камеры (повернутой на углы эйлера)? Интересует именно система координат камеры, повернутая.

Comment: По поводу углов эйлера: Вы их случайно не из `QQuaternion::toEulerAngles()` взяли?

Comment: Я про мировую систему координат. В OpenGL "вверх" - вдоль оси Y. А тут получается ось Z будет вверх. Собственно тут весь вопрос в том, как мои OpenGL координаты отдать пользователю в виде сферических координат, описанных выше. Углы взял именно оттуда.

Comment: Совет: Пишите @username в начале своих ответов, а то мы не получаем уведомлений. (Это вам уведомления всегда приходят, потому что комменты - под вашим постом.)

Comment: На счет преобразования в полярные координаты есть такая идея: берете вектор `0,0,-1` ("вперед" в координатах камеры), поворачиваете ее на кватернион, задающий положение камеры (вместо того, чтобы сначала получать из него углы эйлера). Потом из получившихся `x`,`y` получаете азимут функцией `atan2`. А угол места получаете из `z` через `asin` или `acos`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, согласен, что так будет проще. Я уже сам подумал получать полярные координаты преобразованием из картезиански. Просто через углы Эйлера казалось проще. Осталось только понять, как в случае с "Z - вверх" правильно вращать саму камеру.

Comment: меня интересует вопрос по поводу исходных уравнений (аналитически), по которым Вы строили свой код. Можете, пожалуйста, их скинуть? Буду благодарен.